# PCIe 4.0 m2 SSD in 3.0 notebook: speeds and general compatibility? (WD SN750 vs SN850)

Tags: laptop, ssd, pci-express, m2-connector

I am in the process of upgrading multiple laptops: a Lenovo L14 AMD, an E15 AMD and a recently ordered Lenovo L14 G2 AMD (5750U) with a 1TB SSD. I was wondering if I should be using the Western Digital SN750 (PCIe 3.0) or the SN850 (PCIe 4.0), as the notebooks of course only support PCIe 3.0.

It should be generally possible to install the newer drive because of its backwards compatibility, but there are no tests or reviews out there which would explain benchmarks, or anything else in this regards.

My concrete question is: can anyone please explain if if would make sense to install a PCIe 4.0 SSD in a PCIe 3.0 slot, and what the data rates would approximately be. Bonus points for explaining the differences on the Western Digital drives which i am eyeballing.

Comment: My concern would be on potential device model "whitelisting" in the UEFI. I know that the laptop vendor(s) do it for WLAN modules. Not sure about NVMe SSDs.

Comment: The newer and more expensive should work (except in the aforementioned case of "whitelisting" which is very rare) but there's no point, comparatively, because it'll be limited to the v3.0 speeds.

Comment: What do you mean? I did replace SSDs in laptops before, and it was not a problem. But interesting concern :)

Comment: If you install a PCIe 4.0 device, into a device that only supports PCIe 3.0, it will of course only run at PCIe 3.0 speeds.  The performance speeds of the device itself, would depend on the type of flash memory the device uses, but would be limited by the PCIe 3.0 bandwidth.  **Why exactly do you have a SN850 if you don't have a device that support it's true performance?**  Q&A format is a horrible venue to compare two products, especially when hardware recommendations, are explicitly NOT allow here on Super User.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ramhound. I am asking this question for exactly this reason - because the PCIe bandwidth would be the limit, i am wondering of the actual performance of the SN850 and if it would perform better than the SN750 in this case.

Comment: Typically SSDs using PCIe 4 interface require more power than those with PCIe 3 (but that differs from SSD to SSD, check the hardware specs and reviews). Therefore the time your notebook can run on battery may decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SN750 uses PCIE x4, while the SN850 uses PCIE x8.

The
[Lenovo L14 AMD](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_L14_Gen_1_AMD/ThinkPad_L14_Gen_1_AMD_Spec.pdf)
only has PCIe 3.0 x4.

So the answer: Your computer is incapable of using the SN850 for better
performance.

In general, installing a PCIe 4.0 SSD in a PCIe 3.0 slot might get a
minuscule and unnoticeable performance boost, so is not worth the effort.

You may find more information in the article
[What Is PCIe 4.0 And Is It Worth It For Gaming?](https://www.gamingscan.com/pcie-4-0-worth-it/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and precise answer.

Comment: M.2 supports up to 4 lanes. PCIe 4.0 provides more bandwidth per lane doesn't make it x8.

Comment: @Nanofunk Besides, if the NAND on SN850 is faster, it could still provide non-trivial performance gain in random or even sequential operations. (Remember that, the "spec" are often "peak maximum", i.e. it may/will not be able to make use of all the bandwidth all the time.)

Comment: @TomYan: Unclear: The limiting speed is the computer's PCIe 3.0 x4. You can't go any faster than that, even if the disk can do PCIe 4.0 speeds and has fast NAND.

Comment: @harrymc: If you have read any relatively-detailed review on any NVMe SSDs, you will know they will start to slow down after their faster SLC "cache" is full. So even the SN850 will probably not be able to maintain at the speed that will fill the bottleneck of PCIe 3.0x4 for lengthy sequential write (let alone random read/write). If the slower NAND chips in it are faster than those in an SN750, you could still benefit from that even if you put it onto a PCIe 3.0 slot.

Comment: Put it in another way, while PCIe 3.0 is *a* bottleneck, it does not necessarily mean your drive can even reach it all the time.

Comment: @TomYan: I confess to not understanding your rejection of my answer. You have added here some general knowledge, but not refuted my answer that the SN850 is an unneeded overkill for this computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the video testing samsung 970 evo plus vs 980 pro (which is similar to sn750 vs sn850)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1WlzO97VfA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).